# Creating a new class under default package

Tags: java, eclipse

New to Java and Eclipse. So I've created a project, and I have the (default package). Underneath I created a class. It looks fine. Then I go ahead a created another class, and I want it to be in the default package, too, but in the Project Explorer the .java file shows up under both (default package) and the /src folder. Is it supposed to be like this? What's the explanation of this. I can't seem to find something 'bout this because I guess it's a weird question.

A small illustration:

```
folder
  src
    (default pacakge)
      file2.java
      file1.java
    file2.java
  JRE System Library
```

If I delete file2, it disappears from both locations. Just want to know why the pathing happens like this, and what makes file1 different that it doesn't show under /src.

An extra note, I'd like to use the default package because I will be using a compiled bycote file that doesn't have any package specified, so I need to leave it as default.

Comment: **src** is the folder where eclipse keeps the .java files...any package will be under it

Comment: I don't think I've ever seen Eclipse do that before. That or I just ignore it :)

Comment: And just don't use the default package anyway.

Answer (score 4):

### Congrats

I think you have found a bug. I can replicate what you see. This only happens in the `Project Explorer` which is not the "normal" view that is used in the Java perspective. The default view is `Package Explorer`.

Here is a screenshot with both of them reproducing your case (With Eclipse Mars.1):

[image: explorers]

### Workaround

Press Refresh (`F5`) or use the `Package Explorer`.

### Why does it happen?

My guess is that not many people are using the default package, and even fewer using it with the `Project Explorer`. <strike>I'll file a bug report.</strike> There is already a report, [Bug 418344](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=418344).

Comment: Ah, thanks so much! 'Cause it just instinctively seemed wrong, and since I'm new i dunno if it's something that I did wrong. Thanks, I'll be using the package explorer now. Again, I'll also stir away from using the default package. I'm learning Java for a class and we have to using the default package to run our project with a precompiled bytecode file from the instructor. Thanks again!